# What is the cost with accepting global deliveries?

Tags: simcity-2013

I have an oil power plant. To keep it running, I am accepting global deliveries.
[image]

The expense of running is $856/hour
The burning rate is 8.93k barrels/day (k? what does k mean?).

What is with this $4500 figure? Is it how much it costs to fill my plant or something?

I can "recent transactions" in the budget.

So still with some simple math it does not computer.

```
8.93 barrels /day 
divided by capacity 2000 
= 223 days till i run dry.
```

The recent transaction shows 3 deliveries in just a few months.

[image]

Comment: k stands for kilo, which means thousand.

Comment: What was the "game date" when you took the screenshots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, some in-game time conversions (which can be deduced by comparing the "budget month income" to the "hourly income" in the budget window).

- 24 hours = 1 day = 1 budget month
- 288 hours = 12 days = 12 budget months = 1 budget year

You pay 4500 simoleans for one 1000 barrel shipment of oil on today's market.  When the oil plant is built, it starts with 2000 barrels.

The oil plant burns:

- 1.2 barrels per 2 minutes
- 36 barrels burned in 1 hour
- 864 barrels per day (aka per budget month) - which is worth 3888 simoleans.

The 856 hourly expense is on top of that, so that's another 20544 simoleans daily.

There should be 86% * 12 = 10.3 import shipments per year.  So expect a shipment almost every month.

I would strongly recommend against the oil plant until your city requires over 100 MW.  There is no way to scale the plant's costs back, ala simcity4.

Answer (score 2):

In your screenshots, you're showing 8.93k barrels per day - `k` in this instance stands for kilo. The maximum monthly burn rate for an Oil Powerplant [is reported as 864k barrels per day](http://www.simcityhub.com/power/oil-power-plant).

This means that you're burning 8930 barrels of crude oil per day, or just over 372 barrels of crude oil per hour.

The §856 of expenses per hour is the upkeep of the site and does not include the cost of the oil.

The §4500 reflects the current global market price per truck of oil when imported to your city. Each truck of oil contains 1000 barrels of oil per truck.

Comment: So what quantity of oil does $4500 give me?

Comment: Some of these numbers are not adding up, are you drilling your own oil as well?

Comment: [this forum thread](http://simcityhall.net/viewtopic.php?pid=6944) seems to believe that the inclusion in the `k` is incorrect and is in fact a bug although I cannot vouch for the reliability of the source. Also the numbers still don't add up if you remove the `k`

Comment: I checked your math and everything seems fine.  3000 barrels delivered, 1425 barrels remaining, 1575 barrels used.  Between 4 to 5 months = between 315 to 394 barrels used.  372 fits right in there.

Comment: yes but 372 is the *hourly* burn rate - not the daily or monthly burn rate

Comment: It looks like 8.93 (no k) is the daily burn rate, and would roughly match David's numbers. 8.93 barrels/day X 30 days/month X 5 months = 1339.5 barrels burned.

Comment: Yeah tell me about it - I'm not even able to play the game in the UK until the official Friday release date we have over here otherwise I'd test this myself. It does make sense that 1 real hour = 1 budget month due to the game speed, but during beta I didn't notice any instances of these values recalibrating based on the game speed I had selected.

Comment: @kalina: (sorry fell alseep, you understand, new game :) I am not drilling for my own oil

Comment: great, I like knowing that the truck carries 1000 oil. I will try to spot the truck and take a screenshot.